# Apache HTTPClient that opens a new connection per request?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

Apache HTTPClient tries very hard to manage connections conservatively. Most of the time this is The Right Thing, but sometimes you want to be able to issue requests that just open a new connection for each request without having to worry about connection management semantics.

What's the best way to create such an `HttpClient` in v4.2.5? I'm assuming that the answer will have something to do with a [`ClientConnectionManager`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager.html), but none of the stock implementations seem to do what I want.

I suppose a [`PoolingClientConnectionManager`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html) with a sufficiently large [`setDefaultMaxPerRoute`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html#setDefaultMaxPerRoute%28int%29) and  [`setMaxTotal`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html#setMaxTotal%28int%29) would work, but I'd prefer not to pay the overhead of managing pooled connections.

Comment: I can't think os a *single* instance where the "overhead" of managing those connections is worse than opening a new one.

Comment: Fair point. Still feels like "cheating," though. :/

Answer (score 3):

Simply add 'Connection: close' header to all requests manually or use a custom protocol interceptor to add the header automatically.